# Python Subprocess Error in using "cp"

Tags: python, subprocess, cp

I was trying to use subprocess calls to perform a copy operation (code below):

```
import subprocess
pr1 = subprocess.call(['cp','-r','./testdir1/*','./testdir2/'], shell = True)
```

and I got an error saying:

```
cp: missing file operand

Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

When I try with `shell=False` , I get

```
cp: cannot stat `./testdir1/*': No such file or directory
```

How do I get around this problem?

I'm using RedHat Linux GNOME Deskop version 2.16.0 and bash shell and Python 2.6

P.S. I read the question posted in [Problems with issuing cp command with Popen in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267774/problems-with-issuing-cp-command-with-popen-in-python), and it suggested using `shell = True` option, which is not working for me as I mentioned :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When using `shell=True`, pass a string, not a list to `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call('cp -r ./testdir1/* ./testdir2/', shell=True)
```

[The docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself.

So (on Unix), when a list is passed to `subprocess.Popen` (or `subprocess.call`), the first element of the list is interpreted as the command, all the other elements in the list are interpreted as arguments for the *shell*. Since in your case you do not need to pass arguments to the shell, you can just pass a string as the first argument.

Comment: What If I want to do a call like this: `subprocess.call(["cp","-r", "/home/user/logs", directory_logs])` where `directory_logs` is a string in which I have an existing directory. How can I use the `shell=True` option in this case?

Comment: The option `shell=True` is **strongly discouraged** due to [security concerns](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). I posted a safer alternative below.

Comment: @desmond13 You have no wildcards or other shell features in that command, so absolutely no reason to use `shell=True`.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old thread now, but I was just having the same problem.

The problem you were having with this call:

```
subprocess.call(['cp','-r','./testdir1/*','./testdir2/'], shell = False)
```

was that each of the parameters after the first one are quoted. So to the shell sees the command like this:

```
cp '-r' './testdir1/*' './testdir2/'
```

The problem with that is the wildcard character (`*`). The filesystem looks for a file with the literal name '`*`' in the `testdir1` directory, which of course, is not there.

The solution is to make the call like the selected answer using the `shell = True` option and none of the parameters quoted.

Comment: Good explanation. Helped me understand what was happening.

Comment: For complete orhogonality, `'cp'` should be quoted, too. (It really works; the shell discards the quotes before running the command.)

Answer (score 3):

I know that the option of `shell=True` may be tempting but it's always inadvisable due to [security issues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). Instead, you can use a combination of the subprocess and glob modules.

For **Python 3.5 or higher**:

```
import subprocess
import glob

subprocess.run(['cp', '-r'] + glob.glob('./testdir1/*') + ['./testdir2/'])
```

For **Python 3.4 or lower**:

```
import subprocess
import glob

subprocess.call(['cp', '-r'] + glob.glob('./testdir1/*') + ['./testdir2/'])
```