# Find (bash command) doesn't work with subprocess?

Tags: python, sed, find, subprocess, xargs

I have renamed a css class name in a number of (python-django) templates. The css files however are wide-spread across multiple files in multiple directories. I have a python snippet to start renaming from the root dir and then recursively rename all the css files.

```
from os import walk, curdir
import subprocess

COMMAND = "find %s -iname *.css | xargs sed -i s/[Ff][Oo][Oo]/bar/g"
test_command = 'echo "This is just a test. DIR: %s"'

def renamer(command):
  print command  # Please ignore the print commands.
  proccess = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  op = proccess.communicate()[0]
  print op

for root, dirs, files in walk(curdir):
  if root:
    command = COMMAND % root
    renamer(command)
```

It doesn't work, gives:

```
find ./cms/djangoapps/contentstore/management/commands/tests -iname *.css | xargs sed -i s/[Ee][Dd][Xx]/gurukul/g
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

find ./cms/djangoapps/contentstore/views -iname *.css | xargs sed -i s/[Ee][Dd][Xx]/gurukul/g
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

When I copy and run the same command (printed above), `find` doesn't error out and sed either gets no input files or it works.

What is wrong with the python snippet?

Comment: You need to use `shell=True` for the pipes to work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267803/1599111) for example.

Comment: You don't need a pipe in this case: `op = subprocess.check_output(["find", root]+ r"-iname \*.css -exec sed -i s/foo/bar/gi {} +".split())`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not trying to run a single command, but a shell pipeline of multiple commands, and you're trying to do it without invoking the shell. That can't possibly work. The way you're doing this, `|` is just one of the arguments to `find`, which is why `find` is telling you that it doesn't understand that argument with that "paths must precede expression: |" error.

You *can* fix that by adding `shell=True` to your `Popen`.

But a better solution is to do the pipeline in Python and keep the shell out of it. See [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module) in the docs for an explanation, but I'll show an example.

Meanwhile, you should never use `split` to split a command line. The best solution is to write the list of separate arguments instead of joining them up into a string just to split them out. If you must do that, use the `shlex` module; that's what it's for. But in your case, even that won't help you, because you're inserting random strings verbatim, which could easily have spaces or quotes in them, and there's no way anything—`shlex` or otherwise—can reconstruct the data in the first place.

So:

```
pfind = Popen(['find', root, '-iname', '*.css'], stdout=PIPE)
pxargs = Popen(['xargs', 'sed', '-i', 's/[Ff][Oo][Oo]/bar/g'], 
               stdin=pfind.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
pfind.stdout.close()
output = pxargs.communicate()
```

---

But there's an even better solution here.

Python has `os.walk` to do the same thing as `find`, you can simulate `xargs` easily, but there's really no need to do so, and it has its own `re` module to use instead of `sed`. So, why not use them?

Or, conversely, bash is much better at driving and connecting up simple commands than Python, so if you'd rather use `find` and `sed` instead of `os.walk` and `re.sub`, why write the driving script in Python in the first place?

Comment: +1 for nice answer, for both, showing correct ways with examples, and fixing my attempt. I now realize the overlap between `find` and `os.walk` in my effort, was just being pathetically absent minded at it.

Comment: One reason to use find and rather than os.walk is that find is much faster. os.walk does a sys call for every file, although python 3.5+ have a new function, os.scandir that uses the same sys call find does and has performance more comparable to find

Comment: @twneale Actually, `scandir` doesn't use the same syscall `find` does (at least on modern GNU and BSD systems). That would be `fts`. (Last I checked, there is a lib that wraps `fts` for Python, but I had some problems with it, so I wrote my own incomplete wrapper with `ctypes`. Maybe there's a better one now.) On FreeBSD, `fts` can be a lot faster; on linux (which, at least for some filesystems, lookahead-caches amazingly) or OS X (where some key optimizations don't work on Apple's filesystems) you're probably fine with `scandir`. But first make sure there really is a performance problem…

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the pipe. To use a pipe with the subprocess module, you have to pass `shell=True`.

Comment: abarnert's answer is way more accurate than mine. Go with that.