# Python subprocess doesn't work with my find expression

Tags: subprocess

This works in my terminal:

```
find "/tmp/pic" \( -iname *.JPG  \) | parallel -j 3 convert {} -resize 1920x -quality 60 "/tmp/pic2/{/}"
```

This doesn't work with python:

```
from subprocess import call
import shlex

call(shlex.split('find "/tmp/pic" \( -iname *.JPG  \) | parallel -j 3 convert {} -resize 1920x -quality 60 "/tmp/pic2/{/}"'), shell=True)
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868457/finde-bash-command-doesnt-work-with-subprocess) question with the same error. But the suggested solution (`shell=True`) doesn't work. The solution with `os.walk` described of @abarnert sounds logical, but I just would like to understand what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell does the splitting for you:

```
from subprocess import call

call('find "/tmp/pic" \( -iname *.JPG  \) | parallel -j 3 convert {} -resize 1920x -quality 6\
0 "/tmp/pic2/{/}"', shell=True)
```

Comment: Oh my god. That's too simple. Thank you!